# Create pdf file like image below

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, jspdf

i want to export my data to pdf file. Here is my pdf example.
Any one can help me to make **text inside rectangle** like this image?

[image]

Comment: what had you tried ?

Comment: Did you do any code? Do you use TCPDF or another one?